# Function that adds a bitmap from the library to stage by specifying the name of the bitmap, and the x coordinate and the y coordinate?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

How can I create a function that adds bitmap from the library to stage that can specify the name of the bitmap, the `x` coordinate and the `y` coordinate?

Here is a sampe of my code

```
function getsymbol(ns:String, myX:Number, myY:Number):void { 
    var bd:BitmapData = new ns (50, 100); 
    var img:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd); 
    img.x = myX; 
    img.y = myY; 
    this.addChild(img); 
} 

getsymbol(Abudment, 0, 23)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your bitmap AS Linkage, such as here where the name of the bitmap is `Mushroom`:

[image: library]

In code, obtain the class of the symbol by name using `getDefinitionByname`.

This name is the *As Linkage* name you specify for the symbol in the library.

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

function getSymbol(symbolName:String, x:Number, y:Number):void {
    var c:Class = getDefinitionByName(symbolName) as Class;
    var bd:BitmapData = new c(0, 0) as BitmapData;
    var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
    b.x = x;
    b.y = y;
    addChild(b);
}

getSymbol("Mushroom", 20, 40);
```

The above code will produce:

[image: mushroom]